# How many analog inputs can be read and how many digital inputs can be read from STM32F4 discovery board?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, stm32, adc, gpio

I am using STM32F4 discovery board,exact part no. of controller is STM32F407VGT6. The kit has 3 ADCs each of 12 bit and each ADC has 16 channels.I want to read 40-50 analog inputs.Is there some way to do it without using additional hardware? How many pins of STM32F4 discovery board can be used as analog pins for reading voltage from (0-3) V.  without In the data sheet it was written that most of the pins can be configured as analog pins.Moreover, how many pins can be configured as digital pins for reading digital input

Comment: The ADCs share 16 channels, to get to 40-50 inputs you will need to use some switching or analogue muxes external to the mcu. The data you need is all in the datasheet, study the pinout information, it tells you what each pin can do, the schematic for the discovery board is available on the ST website

Comment: Read the fine data sheet.

Comment: We won't do the counting for you. Open up the Nucleo schematics and chip datasheet and start counting which pins are freely available and which of them can be used as analog inputs and which of them can be used as digital inputs. Other way to do it is to start CubeMX tool, start planning the IO map with the Nucleo board preselected, and start adding analog and digital inputs until there are none available.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer will be in the data sheet.

Comment: I have viewed the datasheet. Apparently there are 16 channels for each ADC and any one of the ADCs can be configured to read data from any channel.In that case, we can read only 16 analog inputs.But in the datasheet it is already written that most of the pins can be configured as analog pins which means we should be able to read data from those pins also and convert it through ADC.Can someone confirm that some pin other than those 16 pins can be configured to read analog data?

Comment: Otherwise let's say we make some other pin(other than those 16 pins) as analog input.What will be its purpose because ADC can only read data from 16 fixed channel pins?

Comment: Look at the alternate function settings for each pin.  If it can be used with an ADC it will be there.  It's possible you will have to do some reconfiguration in the course of scanning all of the analog pins.